# Replace certain contents in a string if exists in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure

I have already searched the website, but did not find a suitable answer to my particular question on substring replacements. I know how to replace substring/regexp via `clojure.string/replace` but am not sure to to utilize it in this case.

Let us say. I have some strings at first place:

```clj
(def test-str "I am a test string. :name to replace, :age to replace. And there are strange symbols in this string. And here are the keyword shall not modify, such as :not-interested.")
(def another-test-str ":nothing :to :replace")
```

And I have a translation table:

```clj
(def translation-table {:name "Alice"
                :age  19})
```

I want to replace `:name` in `test-str` with "Alice", `:age` with 19, but do not want to replace `:not-interested`. The table is long, and different strings (to be replaced) contains different keywords.

Given the translation table, what is a possible systematic way of doing the substring replacement then? Namely, I want a function `replace-with-translation`:

```clj
(replace-with-translation test-str translation-table)
=> "I am a test string. Alice to replace, 19 to replace. And there are strange symbols in this string. And here are the keyword shall not modify, such as :not-interested."

(replace-with-translation another-test-str translation-table)
=> ":nothing :to :replace"

(replace-with-translation test-str {})
=> "I am a test string. :name to replace, :age to replace. And there are strange symbols in this string. And here are the keyword shall not modify, such as :not-interested."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a function to apply the `str/replace` to each pair of target/value in the map.  Here is how I would do it:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]
    [tupelo.schema :as tsk]
    [clojure.string :as str]))


(def test-str "I am a test string. :name to replace, :age to replace. And there are strange symbols in this string. And here are the keyword shall not modify, such as :not-interested.")
(def another-test-str ":nothing :to :replace")

(def translation-table {:name "Alice"
                        :age  19})

(s/defn replace-with-translation :- s/Str
  [template-str :- s/Str
   tx-table :- tsk/KeyMap]
  (let [tx-tgts                (mapv pr-str (keys tx-table)) ; convert all keywords => string
        tx-vals                (mapv str (vals tx-table)) ; coerce any integers => string
        tx-pairs               (mapv vector tx-tgts tx-vals)
        ; ^^^ example:  tx-pairs => [[":name" "Alice"] [":age" "19"]]

        replace-placeholder-fn (fn [result tx-pair]
                                 (let [[tx-tgt tx-val] tx-pair]
                                   (str/replace result tx-tgt tx-val)))
        result-str             (reduce
                                 replace-placeholder-fn
                                 template-str
                                 tx-pairs)]
    result-str))
```

The unit tests show the code in action:

```
(dotest
  (is= (replace-with-translation test-str translation-table)
    "I am a test string. Alice to replace, 19 to replace. And there are strange symbols in this string. And here are the keyword shall not modify, such as :not-interested.")
  (is= (replace-with-translation another-test-str translation-table)
    ":nothing :to :replace")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, loop-over the keys in `translation-table` will definitely do it with careful treatment of corner cases.

Answer (score 7):

`string/replace` can use a function as the replacement, and `get` (retrieving from the map) takes an optional argument to use in case the entry was missing.  Together, those features lend themselves to a concise solution:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as string])

(defn replace-with-translation [s m]
  (string/replace s #":([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)" 
    (fn [[r k]]
      (str (get m (keyword k) r)))))
```

P.S. That regex does not completely account for all possible keywords, but if it meets your requirements then it has the advantage of most likely also working in ClojureScript.

Comment: this one is an absolute winner, since it does it in one pass, and also allows a flexible logic for the keys, that are present in a template, but absent in a dictionary, in contrast with other solutions making regex from dict keys. So it looks like it should be faster AND is more flexible AND more idiomatic

Comment: also, the regex can be rewritten to `#":([\w\-]+)"`, \w === [A-Za-z0-9_]

Answer (score 2):

A one liner:

```clj
(reduce (fn [s [k v]] (str/replace s (str k) (str v)))
        "I am a test string. :name to replace, :age to replace. And there are strange symbols in this string. And here are the keyword shall not modify, such as :not-interested."
        {:name "Alice"
         :age  19})
;; => "I am a test string. Alice to replace, 19 to replace. And there are strange symbols in this string. And here are the keyword shall not modify, such as :not-interested."
```

Or you can make your translation-table to be string->string first. With that you can avoid the repeated calls to `replace`.

```clj
(let [translation-table {":name" "Alice"
                         ":age"  "19"}
      pat               (->> translation-table
                             keys
                             (str/join "|")
                             re-pattern)]
  (time
   (str/replace "I am a test string. :name to replace, :age to replace. And there are strange symbols in this string. And here are the keyword shall not modify, such as :not-interested."
                pat
                translation-table)))
;; "Elapsed time: 0.0258 msecs"
;; => "I am a test string. Alice to replace, 19 to replace. And there are strange symbols in this string. And here are the keyword shall not modify, such as :not-interested."
```

...previous version is `0.1345 msecs`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a corner case question for you.

What if the value of `translation-table` was `{:not-in "foo"}`?

Would you want `(replace-with-translation "such as :not-interested." translation-table)` to return:

(a) `"such as footerested."`

(b) `"such as :not-interested."`

(c) Something else?

If the answer is (a), then I can show you how to implement that using one or more calls to `clojure.string/replace`.

If the answer is (b), then it opens up all kinds of corner case questions of how you want to decide whether an occurrence of the characters ":not-in" should be matched on, or should not be matched on, in the string where replacements might be made.

Comment: Thank you for comments. It shall be (b) in my case.

Comment: I do not know if this is a decision under your control, but if you can make the strings to be replaced have explicit delimiters characters like (replace-with-translation "such as [:not-interested]" translation-table), it will be much easier to do the replacements as you wish, without replacing things you do not want to.